# Tensorflow v2 / Keras. Transfer weights from one model to another

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a tensorflow model (model 1) saved with model.save_weights, I can of course restore the entire model with model.load_weights.

If i change the architecture (model 2), how can i still load the encoder from model 1 and transfer that to model 2? Setting by_name=True and skip_mismatch=True still yields

```
ValueError: Shapes (1, 1, 16, 3) and (1, 1, 16, 2) are incompatible
```

It seems possible with tf.train.load_checkpoint but not only are the variable names a little strange (Containing .ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE in the name) but it also seems like a sub optimal solution.

Does anyone know how to do transfer learning in an elegant way?

Best regards

Comment: Found this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29383
It might be related

Comment: It depends on what changes you made to the architecture, it is not always possible to load weights, as you probably already found out.

Comment: It should still be possible to load the parts of the model that fit. e.g the entire encoder or the entire network without the prediction layer (in case we change the number of categories we can predict)